# Is this set a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Sorry for this picture edit but I accidently editted this entire question. If mods see this please roll it back to 1 hour ago, I cannot do it.. However I had a screenshot of my old question:

[image]

Comment: You can't choose different values for $t$ to be at the same time. So no, it doesn't have $\binom{0}{0}$ and hence isn't a linear subspace.

Comment: @Hayden Oh you are right so 2.) will fail and we can already deduce from this that it's not a linear subspace?

Comment: It is definitely non-empty. Pick any value of $t$ to get a point.  However, it doesn't satisfy (3)(ii), since $0\cdot U_1 = \binom{0}{0} \notin U$.

Comment: But how did you do 3.) for this task? I don't understand..

Comment: If (3)(ii) was true, then for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and every $U_1 \in U$, we would need $\lambda U_1 \in U$.  But, in fact, for *any choice* of $U_1$, we don't have $0 U_1 \in U$, so (3)(ii) is not true.  Hence, $U$ is not a subspace

Comment: Ok thank you Hayden. Would it be enough after fail of 2.) to deduce it's not a linear subspace?

Comment: If (2) was false, yes.  However, it is not false in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the three things you mentioned + that the $0$ vector is also in that subspace (which actually settles the second thing you said you need to chose).

Note that the set is $U = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}1-t \\ t+3\end{pmatrix} | t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$, i.e. the $t$ you choose is the same for the $x$ coordinate and the $y$ coordinate, you can't choose a special $t$ for each. Check again if the zero vector is in $U$ after mentioning this.

Comment: Thanks for answer! See my comment under Hayden, is it correct?

Comment: Note that checking if $U$ contains the zero vector is covered in 3ii.

Comment: No, the space is not empty. From example, for $t = 1$, we get $\begin{pmatrix}0\\4\end{pmatrix}$, so $U$ is not empty. The thing you need to check is if this subspace contains the zero vector.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do 3. please?

Comment: @NMEM You are correct, but somehow I find it more immediate to check if the zero vector is included

Comment: @cnmesr The three things you need to check in order to determine whether a set is a subspace or not are: (i) Closure under addition; (ii) Closuer under scalar multiplication; (iib) $(0, 0)$ is an element. Do that

Comment: @Joshhh I guess if you do that, you can drop ii. Matter of preference I guess.

Comment: @NMEM That is not necessarily true. Take any non-linear surface that goes through the origin. For example a unit sphere centered around $(1,0,0)$ surely isn't closed under scalar multiplication

Comment: @Joshhh Perhaps I misunderstood. I am simply claiming that if you explicitly check that your space has the zero vector, then you don't need to prove that it is nonempty. Likewise, if you prove that a set is closed under linear combination and is nonempty, then you don't need to prove it contains the zero vector. In other words, you can replace ii with "U contains the zero vector." EDIT. I understand my confusion. By ii I meant 2. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

For $t=1$, $U_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\4\end{pmatrix} $ is in $U$.
So for 3 ii we need $$\lambda U_1 \in U$$
Does this hold for one $\lambda$ besides $\lambda = 1$?

Or in other words is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\\lambda 4 \end{pmatrix}\in U$$
for any other $\lambda$ besides $\lambda = 1$?